# PIL weird error after resizing image in skimage

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I observed this weird issue with PIL and scikit image. When I do

```
img=io.imread(imgLoc)
pilImg=Image.fromarray(img)
```

It runs perfect. When I try to resize the image using skimage's rescale method like this:

```
img=rescale(io.imread(imgLoc),0.5)
pilImg=Image.fromarray(img)
```

it says

```
File "/home/abc/activepython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2137, in fromarray
raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

From the documentation of [skimage.io.imread](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#imread) and [skimage.transform.rescale](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#rescale) both returns `numpy.ndarray` which I manually checked as well. Can anyone throw some insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rescale` returns a floating point image. Try to do `pilImg=Image.fromarray(skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(img))`.